# gson.fromjson() causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json

Trying to populate `ListView` by loading items as JSON, so I am using `gson` to simplify things. This is the code which causes error:

```
private void showData(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Movie_Skeleton movie = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Movie_Skeleton.class);
    List<Post> posts = movie.getPosts();

    for(Post p1:posts)
    {
        Log.w("PREMIERE:::",""+p1.getTitle());
    }



    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, posts);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I am able to log the json string perfect in `jsonString` , but having trouble to store the items using `gson.fromJson()` . `posts` seems to be empty, and throws a NullPointerException, what might be causing this? The related classes are provided, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

**MovieSkeleton.class**

```
    public class Movie_Skeleton
{


        int page;

        List<Post> result;

        public int getPage() {
            return page;
        }

        public void setPage(int page) {
            this.page = page;
        }


        public List<Post> getPosts() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setPosts(List<Post> result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

}
```

**Post.class**

```
    public class Post
{



    String poster_path;
    Boolean adult;
    String overview;
    String release_date;
    int[] genre_ids = new int[3];
    int id;
    String original_title;
    String original_language;
    String title;
    String backdrop_path;
    double popularity;
    int vote_count;
    Boolean video;
    double vote_average;

    public String getPoster_path()
    {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path(String poster_path)
    {
        this.poster_path=poster_path;
    }

    public Boolean getAdult()
    {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(Boolean adult)
    {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview()
    {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview)
    {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getRelease_date()
    {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release_date)
    {
        this.release_date = release_date;
    }

    public int[] getGenre_ids()
    {
        return genre_ids;
    }

    public void setGenre_ids(int[] genre_ids)
    {
        this.genre_ids[0] = genre_ids[0];

        this.genre_ids[1] = genre_ids[1];

        this.genre_ids[2] = genre_ids[2];
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getOriginal_title()
    {
        return original_title;
    }

    public void setOriginal_title(String original_title)
    {
        this.original_title = original_title;
    }

    public String getOriginal_language()
    {
        return original_language;
    }

    public void setOriginal_language(String original_language)
    {
        this.original_language = original_language;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public String getBackdrop_path() {
        return backdrop_path;
    }

    public void setBackdrop_path(String backdrop_path) {
        this.backdrop_path = backdrop_path;
    }


    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setTitle(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }


    public int getVote_count() {
        return vote_count;
    }

    public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
        this.vote_count = vote_count;
    }

    public Boolean getVideo()
    {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video)
    {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public Double getVote_average() {
        return vote_average;
    }

    public void setVote_average(Double vote_average) {
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
    }



}
```

**EDIT 1**

This is the json file:
[image]

Comment: `for(Post p1:posts)` on this line : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference  , thats the error!

Comment: Does jsonString is a valid JSON ? Could you verify that?

Comment: Yes, I did verify that, two times, I am getting that as a complete perfect String

Comment: There could be a problem with your Post class, could you comment out "List<Post> result;" from your Movie_Skeleton and try that to see if you are getting "page" variable or not?

Comment: And also could you provide your JSON as a string to here for testing.

Comment: `List<Post> result;` should  be `List<Post> results;`

Comment: Could you try to make List<int> genre_ids instead of int[] genre_ids ?

Comment: @Blackbelt , that solved it! haha, excited, and Thanks :D

Comment: Post that as an Answer, to finish off this question :)

Comment: no need for answer. It was just a typo